# if using the proc report procedure in SAS ,how to stop the proc report procedure?

Tags: sas, report, proc

If using the proc report procedure in SAS, how to stop the proc report procedure?
I try to use "RUN" statement or "quit" statement, but these statements cannot solve the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need the NOWD (NoWindow) option on your proc report statement.

Its leftover from when people used the interactive report builder interface.

```
Proc report data = have nowd;
```